Seekbar with gradient and balloon indicator flutter
This is i need to design but spend amount is not fitting in view with ballon indicator properly, I tried giving fix width to baar but in android  looking different
Widget pendingDiscount(double progressAmount,double emptyBar) {
final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
return Container(
 // color: Colors.green[100],
  height: 120,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:12,right: 12),
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Container(
          height: 30,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0, bottom: 0),
          child: CoreTag(
            radius: 20,
            backgroundColor: CoreColor.neutral100,
            borderColor: Colors.transparent,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                minAmount(width: 35),
                5.width,
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                   // color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                ),
                5.width,
                maxAmount(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),

      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        child: Container(
          height: 70,
          width: 70,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 30,bottom: 20),
          child: upBalloon(false, amount: getRemainingAmount()),
        ),
      ),

      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Container(
        //  color: Colors.red[100],
          width: emptyBar,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0,right: 20),
          height: 12,
          child:   Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [
               Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: SizedBox(
                  //width: 300,
                  child: EmptyLine(width: emptyBar),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  children: [
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: SeekLine(
                          width: progressAmount
                       // width: emptyBar > progressAmount ? emptyBar - progressAmount : emptyBar ,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: CircleView(
                        colors: CoreColor.dataVis,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: Container(
          //16+12+5+50
          // color: Colors.red[100],
          margin:  EdgeInsets.only(left: progressAmount < 250 ? progressAmount +10: progressAmount - 60,top: 55),
          child: pendingDownBalloon(amount: getSpendAmount()),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);

}
this how i'm calling
// - 60 is the value of remaining in 300 k and width is 220
      var spendAmount = widget.discount?.totalSpent / 1000.toDouble() - 50;
      return pendingDiscount(spendAmount,emptyBar);

down baloon
Widget pendingDownBalloon({String amount = '0', bool? isDoneState}) {
  return Container(
    height: 70,
    width: 70,
   // color: Colors.limeAccent[100],
    child: Column(
      children: [
        const CircleView(
          colors: CoreColor.accentGold,
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 5,
        ),
        isDoneState == null
            ? Assets.svgs.blueBalloon.svg()
            : Assets.svgs.yellowDownBalloon.svg(),
        Text(
          '\$${amount}',
          style: CoreTextStyle.mMedium.copyWith(
              color:
                  isDoneState == null ? CoreColor.dataVis : CoreColor.accentGold),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

SeekBar, Empty line, max and min amt widget
 class SeekLine extends StatelessWidget {
  final double radius;
  final double width;

  const SeekLine({super.key, this.radius = 4, this.width = 0});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      key: seekKey,
      width: width,
      height: 5,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: CoreColor.gradient08,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(radius)),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class EmptyLine extends StatelessWidget {
  final double radius;
  final double width;

  const EmptyLine({super.key, this.radius = 4, this.width = 0});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: width,
      height: 5,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: CoreColor.neutral200,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(radius)),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CircleView extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color colors;

  const CircleView({super.key, required this.colors});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 10,
      height: 10,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        color: colors,
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget minAmount({double? width}) {
  return SizedBox(
    width: width ?? 40,
    child: const Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text('\$0K', style: CoreTextStyle.mRegular),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

Widget maxAmount() => const SizedBox(
      width: 50,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          Text('\$300K', style: CoreTextStyle.mRegular),
        ],
      ),
    );

Up ballon
Widget upBalloon(bool isZeroState, {String amount = '300.00'}) {
  return Column(
    children: [
      Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Visibility(visible: isZeroState, child: const Text('')),
          Text(
            isZeroState ? '\$300.00K' : '\$${amount}',
            style: CoreTextStyle.mMedium.copyWith(color: CoreColor.accentGold),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Assets.svgs.yellowBalloon.svg(),
    ],
  );
}



Please share CoreTag class also for code clarification.

@DroidFlutter it is just light grey background with rounded corner and question is edited

Because the library doesn't support custom indicators, it only allows custom step. I suggest you create a stack => calculate where the ballon should be => wrap it with Position

@ToraCode please help me to calculate, i created line but creating balloon is tricky, let me update code

@FarhanaNaazAnsari I have added code for it, check if it works for you.

I have made some changes in your class, check if it helps...
double _width = 0;

class LinePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // Draw the gray background line
    final backgroundPaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.grey[300]!
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeWidth = 5;

    final centerY = size.height / 2;
    canvas.drawLine(
      Offset(0, centerY),
      Offset(size.width, centerY),
      backgroundPaint,
    );

    // Draw the gradient line
    final gradientPaint = Paint()
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeWidth = 5;

    canvas.drawLine(
      Offset(0, centerY),
      Offset(size.width * 2 / 3, centerY),
      gradientPaint,
    );

    // Draw circles at both ends
    final blueCirclePaint = Paint()..color = Colors.blue;
    final orangeCirclePaint = Paint()..color = Colors.orange;

    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(0, centerY), 5, blueCirclePaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(size.width * 2 / 3, centerY), 5, orangeCirclePaint);
    _width = (size.width * 2 / 3);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}

And you main class like below
Container(
        height: 50,
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          children: [
            CustomPaint(
              size: Size(300, 5), // Set the desired size of the custom paint area
              painter: LinePainter(),
            ),
            Positioned(
                left: _width - 20,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Icon(Icons.ballot_outlined),
                )),
          ],
        ),
      ),

Change icon with your balloon icon

You can follow creating a SeekBar with gradient and balloon indicators in Flutter:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DiscountWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final double progressAmount;
  final double emptyBar;

  const DiscountWidget({Key? key, required this.progressAmount, required this.emptyBar}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Container(
      height: 120,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Container(
              height: 30,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0),
              child: CoreTag(
                radius: 20,
                backgroundColor: CoreColor.neutral100,
                borderColor: Colors.transparent,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    minAmount(width: 35),
                    SizedBox(width: 5),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 5),
                    maxAmount(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            child: Container(
              height: 70,
              width: 70,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 30, bottom: 20),
              child: upBalloon(false, amount: getRemainingAmount()),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Container(
              width: emptyBar,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, right: 20),
              height: 12,
              child: Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                children: [
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: SizedBox(
                      child: EmptyLine(width: emptyBar),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Stack(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      children: [
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: SeekLine(width: progressAmount),
                        ),
                        const Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: CircleView(
                            colors: CoreColor.dataVis,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: progressAmount < 250 ? progressAmount + 10 : progressAmount - 60,
                top: 55,
              ),
              child: pendingDownBalloon(amount: getSpendAmount()),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget pendingDownBalloon({String amount = '0', bool? isDoneState}) {
  return Container(
    height: 70,
    width: 70,
    child: Column(
      children: [
        const CircleView(
          colors: CoreColor.accentGold,
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 5),
        isDoneState == null ? Assets.svgs.blueBalloon.svg() : Assets.svgs.yellowDownBalloon.svg(),
        Text(
          '\$${amount}',
          style: CoreTextStyle.mMedium.copyWith(
            color: isDoneState == null ? CoreColor.dataVis : CoreColor.accentGold,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

class SeekLine extends StatelessWidget {
  final double radius;
  final double width;

  const SeekLine({Key? key, this.radius = 4, this.width = 0}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: width,
      height: 5,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: CoreColor.gradient08,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(radius)),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class EmptyLine extends StatelessWidget {
  final double radius;
  final double width;

  const EmptyLine({Key? key, this.radius = 4, this.width = 0}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: width,
      height: 5,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: CoreColor.neutral200,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(radius)),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CircleView extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color colors;

  const CircleView({Key? key, required this.colors}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 10,
      height: 10,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        color: colors,
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget minAmount({double? width}) {
  return SizedBox(
    width: width ?? 40,
    child: const Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text('\$0K', style: CoreTextStyle.mRegular),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

Widget maxAmount() => const SizedBox(
      width: 50,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          Text('\$300K', style: CoreTextStyle.mRegular),
        ],
      ),
    );

Widget upBalloon(bool isZeroState, {String amount = '300.00'}) {
  return Column(
    children: [
      Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Visibility(visible: isZeroState, child: const Text('')),
          Text(
            isZeroState ? '\$300.00K' : '\$${amount}',
            style: CoreTextStyle.mMedium.copyWith(color: CoreColor.accentGold),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Assets.svgs.yellowBalloon.svg(),
    ],
  );
}

I hope this will help to solve it.
